# Displaying results of multiple async Tasks in a single list

Tags: android, list, datasource

**Original Screen**

I have had a screen with a spinner at the top when the user selects a value from the spinner we display the items for that selection in the list below.

The data is obtained from a server using the async task in a paginated fashion, as the user scrolls, more data is obtained from the server using the async task to add to the list. (i..e get items 1 to 20, when the user scrolls down, get items 21 to 40).

For Example: when you select "Bucket 1" the list shows you all items in "Bucket 1", then when you select "Bucket 2" the list changes to display all the items in "Bucket 2".  We never know how many items there are in each bucket, the numbers can vary.

[image]

**New Desired Screen**

I need to change this screen so that I no longer use a spinner.

Instead, I want to have **one** list that contains **all** the items from **all** the buckets (see image below).  I want to display all items from bucket 1, then all items from bucket 2 and so on.

*Note: I may or may not want the dividing rows showing the name of the bucket,*

The problem I have is that the server only permits me to get items for one bucket at a time, therefore I will have to call to get the items from bucket 1, then as the user scrolls if I run out of items from bucket 1 get the items from bucket 2 and so on.

I need to have all items in a single list so I can select multiple items across buckets.

[image]

**Help**

How do I code such a list?  The list is having data coming from MULTIPLE DIFFERENT async calls.

I guess I have to start with making calls to count how many items there are in total across all buckets and that is my list count.

I have seen there is a "MergeCursor" but this won't help me as I am not getting data from a database.

I have seen there is a "MergeAdapter" which is one adapter that contains child adapters. In my case, I would have 1 child adapter for every bucket. My MergeAdapter count would be the total count of all child items and then when getting the view/items for each row I would have to use the position and size of each bucket to know which bucket to get the item from.

Any suggestions of a way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, use RecyclerView instead of ListView and RxJava instead of async tasks - this way you can use zip method there.

Comment: Does data in each bucket is the same type?

Comment: Szymon Chaber - Yes I am likely to use RecyclerView not ListView - That was my mistake in the title, sorry to be misleading

Comment: grabarz121 - Yes all the data in the buckets are the same type

Comment: Szymon Chaber - unfortuntely I am not sure if i can use 3rd party library. I will take a look at this though and see if this would help me, thank you

Comment: Doesn't RxJava zip get all items from the 1st bucket & merge with all items from the 2nd before it returns? If so its not suitable for perf reasons. I could have a lot of items in 1 bucket & I don't wait to wait until its got all items from all buckets before list is populated. I want to get the first 20 items (or so) from the server, then the next 20 when the user scrolls, etc.The 1st batch could be all 5 items from bucket 1& 15 items from bucket 2 (which has 30 items). Or it could be 20 items from bucket 1 which had 80 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in the AsyncTask getting the items from the server.  The adapter passes to the task what rows it wants the data for. The task then finds out if bucket 1 has these items, if it does it returns then, if it doesn't have all of them the size of the first bucket is removed from the adapter count, and the second bucket is checked and so on until all the items are returned.

Example

Bucket 1 : 5 items (A,B,C,D,E)
Bucket 2 : 3 items (F,G,H)
Bucket 3 : 10 items (I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,R,S)

Adapter asks for items 1 - 4 :

- SyncTask return items 1 - 4  from Bucket 1
- Total returned = A,B,C,D

Adapter asks for items 5 - 8 :

- SyncTask first sees if bucket 1 has 5 or more items, as it does, it gets the 5th item from bucket one, E
- The SyncTask only has 1 item when it has been asked for 4 items, and bucket 1 has run out of items. Therefore the SyncTask looks in Bucket 2.  The count is adjusted to remove the number of items in bucket 1, so the new count is asking for 1 - 3 in Bucket 2, which are returned, F,G,H
- Total returned = E,F,G,H

Adapter asks for items 9-12

- The AsyncTask checks if the starting number is more than the number in the first bucket, it is so AsyncTask creates a new count by taking off total from Bucket 1
- So we are looking for 4 - 7
- The AsyncTask then checks if the starting number is more than the number in the second bucket, it is so AsyncTask creates a new count by taking off total from Bucket 2 of the updated count
- So we are looking for 1 - 4
- Bucket 3 has 4 or more items so we return the first 4 items
- Total returned = I,J,K,L